# Fixed position for pgfplot area

Tags: pgfplots, best-practices

I use pgfplots to generate graphics for a beamer presentation. The graphics are placed on consecutive slides.

This works great, but the graphic position is slightly moving from slide to slide, which looks unprofessional. This comes from the `xticklabels` which shifts the picture up and down in my case.

Is there a way to force the graphic area to be at the same place on each beamer slide ? Maybe by adding a margin around the graphic area ?

[image]

I used the workaround of creating two overlapping axes, one of them with opacity=0 to fix the position but this isn't an elegant way.

Here is a minimal example :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Slide 1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
\begin{axis}
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Slide 2}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
\begin{axis}
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Slide 3}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
\begin{axis}
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,3)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define a new key `trim axis` that sets the bounding box of the `tikzpicture` to the extent of the plot area. Note that this simple approach won't work if you have several different `axis` environments in a single `tikzpicture`.

```
\tikzset{
    trim axis/.style={
        execute at end picture={
            \pgfresetboundingbox
            \path (current axis.north west) (current axis.south east);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    trim axis/.style={
        execute at end picture={
            \pgfresetboundingbox
            \path (current axis.north west) (current axis.south east);
        }
    }
}

\begin{frame}{Slide 1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis]
\begin{axis}
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Slide 2}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis]
\begin{axis}
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Slide 3}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis]
\begin{axis}
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,3)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```