# standalone document class: "border" option does not work as expected

Tags: pgfplots, standalone

- I want a standalone diagram (`standalone` document class plus `pgfplots` package).
- I want that the diagram doesn't dance around when I have multiple diagrams with different axis limits and so on.
- Therefore I use `scale only axis` and trim the `bounding box` to the axis (see MWE).
- All works fine but the `border` option of the `standalone` package seems not to work.
- **`border = {15mm 0mm 0mm 0mm} % left bottom right top` should add a border to the left side but it adds a border to all four sides.**
- The yellow background is only to make the example clearer.

---

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123880/
\documentclass[
    tikz,
    border = {15mm 0mm 0mm 0mm} % left bottom right top
    ]
    {standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = {$y$},
        xmin = 0,
        xmax = 30,
        ymin = 0,
        ymax = 100,     
        xtick = {0,10,...,30},  
        ytick = {0,10,...,100}, 
        scale only axis,
        % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153708/
        execute at end picture={
            \pgfresetboundingbox
            \path (current axis.north west) (current axis.south east);
        },  
        % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239294
        axis background/.style={fill=yellow}    
    ]
    %
    \addplot[]{x^2};        
    %       
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

### `border = {0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm}`

[image]

---

### `border = {15mm 0mm 0mm 0mm}`

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The option is a bit picky regarding spaces. Compare:

```
\documentclass[
    border={15mm 0mm 0mm 0mm},% works
   % border= {15mm 0mm 0mm 0mm}%wrong borders
    ]
    {standalone}
\begin{document}
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Haha - crazy. Thanks. I think this can be considered a bug. Did you just guess?

Comment: It is not so much a bug but an overstretched use of the class options. The LaTeX code isn't really designed for keyval here, and in this case `zap@space` removes too much spaces in the failing case. There is no need to setup the border already when loading the class, and imho it would be better if there were a `\standalonesetup{...}` command.

Comment: Thanks -- good idea, maybe you mean `\standaloneconfig` since I did not find `\standalonesetup` in the manual.

Comment: Oh there is one ;-). I only looked for "setup". Yes, it is better to use this.